# How do I specify 16 slots in Quake 3

Tags: quake-3

Is there a command that I can run in-game to open up more slots during a networked game of Quake 3 Arena?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line to your `server.cfg`:

```
seta sv_maxclients 16
```

From [here](http://www.quake3world.com/q3guide/servers.html):

> **sv_maxclients 16** - maximum number of players on the server.

You can try using rcon to change this while the server is running:

```
/rcon seta sv_maxclients 16
```

..but even if that *is* possible normally, most hosting companies disallow that because you pay by the number of server-slots.